# Gravação nula no banco de dados!

Tags: php

Fiz a criação do meu formulário, e fiz o teste para gravação no BD. Quando o campo está nulo, ele mostra a mensagem de erro. Quando os campos estão preenchidos, ele mostra a mensagem de dados gravados com sucesso, mas quando eu verifico no branco de dados, não há nenhum dado gravado; 
Não consigo identificar o erro.
Os códigos estão abaixo:

**Conexão:**

```
<?php    
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "cnsmaxim_teste1"; 
$pass = ""; 
$banco = "cnsmaxim_teste"; 

$conexao = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($banco);
?>
```

**Insere:**

```
<?php
    include "conecta_mysql.inc";

$tAut       =$_POST ["tAut"];
$tPrest     =$_POST ["tPrest"];
$tCart      =$_POST ["tCart"];
$cDadm      =$_POST ["cDadm"];
$tNome      =$_POST ["tNome"];
$tNasc      =$_POST ["tNasc"];
$tCnpj      =$_POST ["tCnpj"];
$tNomecont  =$_POST ["tNomecont"];
$tCodcnes   =$_POST ["tCodcnes"];
$tProf      =$_POST ["tProf"];
$tEsp       =$_POST ["tEsp"];
$tConsr     =$_POST ["tConsr"];
$tNcons     =$_POST ["tNcons"];
$tCbos      =$_POST ["tCbos"];
$tDatatm    =$_POST ["tDatatm"];
$tTab       =$_POST ["tTab"];
$tCodp      =$_POST ["tCodp"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO tabteste VALUES ";
$sql .= "('$tAut', '$tPrest', '$tCart', '$cDadm', '$tNome', '$tNasc', '$tCnpj', '$tNomecont', '$tCodcnes', '$tProf', '$tEsp', '$tConsr', '$tNcons', '$tCbos', '$tDatatm', '$tTab', '$tCodp')";
$resultado = mysql_query ($sql);
echo "Dados salvos com sucesso!";
mysql_close ($conexao);
?>
```

**Verifica:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="description" content="Guia de Consulta CNS"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>


<?php

$tAut       =$_POST ["tAut"];
$tPrest     =$_POST ["tPrest"];
$tCart      =$_POST ["tCart"];
$cDadm      =$_POST ["cDadm"];
$tNome      =$_POST ["tNome"];
$tNasc      =$_POST ["tNasc"];
$tCnpj      =$_POST ["tCnpj"];
$tNomecont  =$_POST ["tNomecont"];
$tCodcnes   =$_POST ["tCodcnes"];
$tProf      =$_POST ["tProf"];
$tEsp       =$_POST ["tEsp"];
$tConsr     =$_POST ["tConsr"];
$tNcons     =$_POST ["tNcons"];
$tCbos      =$_POST ["tCbos"];
$tDatatm    =$_POST ["tDatatm"];
$tTab       =$_POST ["tTab"];
$tCodp      =$_POST ["tCodp"];

//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
if (empty($tAut))
{
  $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Autorização obrigatório!<br>';
}
//Verifica se o campo não está embranco.

if (empty($tPrest))
    {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número da Guia do Prestador obrigatório!<br>';
    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.

    if (empty($tCart))
    {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número da Carteirinha obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($cDadm)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Admissão obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tNome)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Nome obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tNasc)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Nascimento obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tCnpj)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do CNPJ obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tNomecont)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Nome do Contratado obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tCodcnes)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Código CNES obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tProf)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento  do Profissional Executante obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tEsp)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Especialidade obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tConsr)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Conselho Regional obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tNcons)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número do Conselho obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tCbos)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Número do CBOS obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tDatatm)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Data de Atendimento obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tTab)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento da Tabela  obrigatório!<br>';

    }
//Verifica se o campo não está em branco.
    if (empty($tCodp)) {
        $error[] = 'Preenchimento do Código do Procedimento obrigatório!<br>';

    }

if (isset($error)){ // se houve erro
    foreach($error as $msg) {
        echo $msg;
    }
} else { // não houve erro
    $error[] = 'Todos os campos preenchidos corretamente!';
    include "insere.php";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faça assim para exibir um possível erro, `$resultado = mysql_query ($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Qual a sua versão do PHP?

Comment: Além da sua versão do PHP, seu PHP.INI está configurado para exibir erros? display_errors = on? Coloque isso no início do seu código: ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @AllanAndrade Tô usando o PHPStorm 2016.1.2

Comment: Você não deveria especificar as colunas em sua query ? Ex: `INSERT INTO tabteste (coluna_tAut, coluna_tPrest, etc.. ) VALUES ('$tAut', '$tPrest', etc...)`...

Comment: @rray Fiz conforme você disse e os dados estão gravando. Porém há dois campos que não gravam. o tAut e o tPrest

Comment: Tentou imprimir  o valor deles?

Comment: @rray Sim. Na verdade, eles estão iguais os outros campos. Mesmo preenchidos, no banco de dados eles ficam sem número. O tAut grava como 0 e o tPrest nulo.

Comment: Pode ser que o nome dos campos no form estão diferentes dos capturados pelo post, poderia colocar o resultado de: `echo $sql;` na pergunta.

Comment: No formulário estava faltando a identificação igual a do post!

Comment: O post não ta passando para o outro arquivo.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @rray Consegui sim. Obrigada!!